# Probability of coin arrangement

Tags: probability

Place coins whose heads are black and tails are white randomly from left to right. When the
coins are placed in an order like [White White Black Black White], you are required to flip the black coins between the white coins. Similarly, when the coins are placed in an order like
[Black, Black, White White Black], you are required to flip the white coins between the black
coins.

(1) What is the probability that all the coins are white, when placing 32 coins following this
rule?
(2) Derive the probability when the numbers of white and black coins are equal.

Thank you very much！

Comment: Are those the only two orders in which you are required to flip the coins? Since you're placing 32 of them, it can't be, but I don't see a general rule for deciding when to flip. Also, to be clear about the process: You place the coins randomly, then flip some based on a rule, and you want the probability of certain arrangements after both steps are complete?

Comment: What's the source of this question? Can you do any special case? What progress have you made on the problem, what ideas do you have about it? Why do you want to know about it? Unsourced, unmotivated problems with no effort shown --- not a good use of this website.

Comment: @Potato Thank you for your attention. I think that a coin was took out randomly, if the orders match the two orders mentioned above, the coins will be flipped. I want to know the probability of certain arrangements after both steps are complete.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This is a question from a math test. I just want to  you know how to solve such kind of coin arrangement questions.

Comment: The question is still very unclear. Are you placing the coins one at a time? and each time you place a coin, you you flip coins if you have to? and are you placing the coins in random places, or are you starting at one end of a line and then placing each coin next to the last one? If this is from a test, can you write out the exact words from the test? (I trust it's a test from the past, not an ongoing test!)

Comment: @GerryMyerson This question is from a test five years ago. But I think it was written by a Japanese teacher. I think we can consider it like this way. Imagining there are lots coins (white or black) in a bags, each time a coin was randomly taken out and placed in a line. if the orders match the two orders mentioned above, the coins will be replaced with the other colour. Take first five coins for example. 1.○ 2.○ 3.● 4.● 5.○ Which is '○○●●○'. According to the rules, the black two one should be replace with white coins, which will be '○○○○○'.

Comment: So, it's only wwbbw and bbwwb that cause a flip? If the first three coins are wbw, no flip occurs? wwbbbw, no flip?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes！Only the wwbbw or bbwwb will cause a flip.